# Question about the distribution of primes in Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

The following comes from Page 57 of Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory. My question is: why is (6) being convergent necessary in deducing the result from (5)?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the Dirichlet series $$\eta(s)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}\,,\quad\Re(s)>0\tag{1}$$ provides some insight as $$\underset{s\to 0^+}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}\right)=\frac{1}{2}=\eta(0)\tag{2}$$ but the Dirichlet series in formula (1) above doesn't actually converge at $s=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you studied the proof of Dirichlet's theorem enough to appreciate how a sum over the primes subject to a congruence condition $a \bmod q$, where $\gcd(a,q) = 1$, can be broken up into a linear combination over all Dirichlet characters mod $q$ of sums over all primes, where the term associated to a prime $p$ is weighted by a factor $\chi(p)$?  This is what Davenport means by "a linear combination of characters in the usual way".

Here is how this idea arises in the proof of Dirichlet's theorem.
When $s > 1$,
$$
\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q} \frac{1}{p^s} = 
\sum_p \frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\left(\sum_{\chi \bmod q} \overline{\chi}(a)\chi(p)\right)\frac{1}{p^s} = 
\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_{\chi \bmod q}\overline{\chi}(a)\sum_p \frac{\chi(p)}{p^s}
$$
and you then separately look at the inner sum on the right where $\chi$ is trivial and the inner sums where $\chi$ is nontrivial: the inner sums at nontrivial $\chi$ are *bounded* as $s \to 1^+$, so
$$
\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q} \frac{1}{p^s} = 
\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s} + O(1)
$$
as $s \to 1^+$. This expresses a sum over $p$ in a congruence class mod $q$ as a sum over all $p$ plus an error term that is $O(1)$ because we know the sums over nontrivial $\chi \bmod q$ are bounded as $s \to 1^+$. Understanding the behavior of $\sum_p 1/p^s$ as $s \to 1^+$ then leads to Dirichlet's theorem in terms of Dirichlet density.

With more work, it turns out that each of
the infinite series $\sum \chi(p)/p^s$ for nontrivial $\chi \bmod q$ is not just bounded as $s \to 1^+$, but it actually *converges* as $s \to 1^+$, say to $C_\chi$, and using this stronger information lets us refine the $O(1)$ error term in the above equation so we can say
$$
\sum_{p\equiv a \bmod q} \frac{1}{p^s} = 
\frac{1}{\varphi(q)}\sum_p \frac{1}{p^s} + C_{a,q} + o(1)
$$
as $s \to 1^+$, where $C_{a,q} = (1/\varphi(q))\sum_{\chi \not= {\rm 1}_q} \overline{\chi}(a)C_\chi$, a constant depending on $a$ and $q$.

You should adapt this to the question you asked: there is no variable $s$ anymore, and now the infinite series over all primes subject to a congruence condition is replaced by a finite sum over the primes $p \leq x$ subject to a congruence condition.  Express that finite sum as a "linear combination in the usual way" of the finite sums $\sum_{p \leq x} \chi(p)/p$ where $\chi$ runs over all Dirichlet characters mod $q$. Then separately consider such sums at trivial $\chi$ using (5) and at all nontrivial $\chi$ using (6).